# Airflow Pipeline CSV to BigQuery with Schema Changes

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

### Background

I'm need to design an Airflow pipeline to load CSV's into BigQuery.

I know the CSV's frequently have a changing schema. After loading the first file the schema might be

`id | ps_1 | ps_1_value`

when the second file lands and I load it it might look like

`id | ps_1 | ps_1_value | ps_1 | ps_2_value`.

### Question

What's the best approach to handling this?

---

My first thought on approaching this would be

1. Load the second file
2. Compare the schema against the current table
3. Update the table, adding two columns (ps_2, ps_2_value)
4. Insert the new rows

I would do this in a PythonOperator.

If file 3 comes in and looks like `id | ps_2 | ps_2_value` I would fill in the missing columns and do the insert.

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Can you explain with more details your first step? Do you load a temporary table with the data to be inserted?

Comment: I could either read the file into a pandas dataframe or yes, load it into a staging table in bigquery, and get the schema from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the recommended pipeline for your case consists in creating a temporary table for treating your new data. 
Since `AirFlow` is an orchestration tool, its not recommended to create big flows of data through it.

Given that, your `DAG` could be very similar to your current `DAG`:

1. Load the new file to a temporary table
2. Compare the actual table's schema and the temporary table's schema.
3. Run a query to move the data from the temporary table to the actual table. If the temporary table has new fields, add them to the actual table using the parameter `schema_update_options`. Besides that, if your actual table has fields in NULLABLE mode, it will be able to easily deal with missing columns case your new data have some missing field.
4. Delete your temporary table
5. If you're using `GCS`, move your file to another bucket or directory.

Finally, I would like to point some links that might be useful to you:

1. [AirFlow Documentation](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.1/code.html#airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator) (BigQuery's operators)
2. An [article](https://medium.com/bakdata/data-warehousing-made-easy-with-google-bigquery-and-apache-airflow-bf62e6c727ed) which shows a problem similar to yours ans where you can find some of the mentioned informations.

I hope it helps

Comment: You were on point with `schema_update_options`, but I don't actually need to load into a temporary table it seems. BigQuery is smart enough to do the work on the insert. Thank you for your help. Will post the full operator below.

Answer (score 6):

After loading two prior files `example_data_1.csv` and `example_data_2.csv` I can see that the fields are being inserted into the correct columns, with new columns being added as needed.

Edit: The light bulb moment was realizing that the `schema_update_options` exist. See here: https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.SchemaUpdateOption.html

```
csv_to_bigquery = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id='csv_to_bigquery',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
    bucket=airflow_bucket,
    source_objects=['data/example_data_3.csv'],
    skip_leading_rows=1,
    bigquery_conn_id='google_cloud_default',    
    destination_project_dataset_table='{}.{}.{}'.format(project, schema, table),
    source_format='CSV',
    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
    write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND',
    schema_update_options=['ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION', 'ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION'],
    autodetect=True,
    dag=dag
)
```

[image]

Comment: Will it work if `write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE'` ?